# Hello all brother How can i post single value and multiple value to database by Javascript json endpoint to Spring Web API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring, api

```
{
        "id": 178,
        "stockin_date": "2022-11-15T08:18:54.252+00:00",
        "effective_date": null,
        "expired_date": null,
        "create_date": null,
        "update_date": null,
        "createby_emId": null,
        "updateby_emId": null,
        "deleteby_name": null,
        "delete_date": null,
        "invoice": "P_008",
        "po": "YSYDV",
        "remark": "Buy from PIC",
        "supply_id": 2,
        "stockinDetail": [
            {
                "id": 272,
                "quantity": 10,
                "unit": "kg",
                "unit_price": 9,
                "stockin_id": 178,
                "pro_id": 74
            },
            {
                "id": 273,
                "quantity": 14,
                "unit": "kg",
                "unit_price": 2,
                "stockin_id": 178,
                "pro_id": 75
            }
        ]
    }
```

How Can I Create javascript that can post data to api post man like this

Hello  all brother How can i post single value and multiple value to database by Javascript json

Comment: Are you asking how to use javascript to send a POST request (with json data) to an api endpoint?

Comment: my endpoin to Spring web api brother

Comment: Are you asking how to use javascript to send a POST request (with json data) to an api endpoint? Saying your api endpoint is built with Spring doesn't answer my question.

Comment: that my process i have one (url: 'http://localhost:8082/stockin/add', ) and i want to post data from javascript to this url and i don't know how can i make this process to prepare  data by javascript before post data to web service 

thank brother for my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a POST request using `fetch` which is built into javascript. Here is a working example with different `data` and a different `url`.

To change this code so it sends the POST request to your `url` with your `data`:

- Change `const data = { "name": "test", ... };` to `const data = { "id": 178, ... };`
- Change `const url = 'https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create';` to `const url = 'http://localhost:8082/stockin/add';`

```js
const data = {
  "name": "test",
  "salary": "123",
  "age": "23"
};
const url = 'https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create';

//send the POST request and handle the response
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```